# How to read EMF - Enhanced metafiles?

Tags: image, .emf

Does anybody know of a library or a piece of code that can read EMF (Enhanced Metafiles). Ideally it would convert an EMF to a list of drawing commands and objects?

Answer (score 3):

The [Apache Image Loader Framework](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/commons/image-loader.html) (Java) can read EMF file and convert then to SVG, it can also read WMF using 3rd party plugin.

Comment: As I found, EMF, unfortunately, is not fully supported by xmlgraphics.
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/graphics.html#emf

When I tried to read EMF file it thrown an error:
"no suitable loader/converter combination available"

And adding FOP dependency didn't fix it.

P.S.
Also, just for sharing my experience to save your time - FreeHep also is not working correctly with EMF. So, don't waste your time trying to run it - it's totally buggy.

Answer (score 2):

What language are you working in ? 
You might look at our MetaDraw ( available as OCX or .NET Winforms component )
This will load EMF files and allow you to cycle through the elements ( lines, shapes, text ).   You can then identify the parameters ( coordinates, line thickness, colors, etc)   More details at www.MetaDraw.com

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) can do it. There is also a python utility called [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) which will do it (using installed LibreOffice libraries). You could look at those for some hints on how it's done, since they're open source.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia article on [Windows Metafile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) has a lot of relevant information on EMF. Check external links for libraries and format specification.